# simple html dom 404 error

Tags: php, web-crawler, simple-html-dom

Hey guys I'm Have this code:

```
<?php

include './simple_html_dom.php';

//this link exists
$teste = new simple_html_dom("http://www.btolinux.com.br/");
echo $teste->original_size."<br>";
if($teste->original_size !== 0){
    $teste->find("html");
}

//At this time I'm forcing get a 404 error link.
$teste = new simple_html_dom("http://www.btolinux.com.br/error/");
echo $teste->original_size."<br>";
if($teste->original_size !== 0){
    $teste->find("html");
}

//Now I'm get the correct link again. Why the error persists?
$teste = new simple_html_dom("http://www.btolinux.com.br/");
echo $teste->original_size."<br>";
if($teste->original_size !== 0){
    $teste->find("html");
}

?>
```

So, in my code, when I found a 404 error link, in the next objects created with the same class, the error persists.
How can I solve this problem?

To try this code get the Simple_dom_php in http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/

Comment: Can you please give a detail explaination

Comment: This code return this error to me:

´Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /var/www/html/crawler/simple_html_dom.php on line 1113´

  my PHP version is 5.5.9-1ubuntu4 (cli)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the @ to avoid warnings, like this:

```
<?php
//CORRECT
$url = "http://www.btolinux.com.br/";
$html = @file_get_contents($url);
if ($html!='') {
    $teste = new simple_html_dom($url);
    echo 'SIZE: '.$teste->original_size."<br>";    
}


//ERROR
$url = "http://www.btolinux.com.br/error/";
$html = @file_get_contents($url);
if ($html!='') {
    $teste = new simple_html_dom($url);
    echo 'SIZE: '.$teste->original_size."<br>";    
}
?>
```

Comment: hmm it's a great idea, but when I use this code whith:
`
$url = "http://www.btolinux.com.br/";
$html = @file_get_contents($url);
if ($html!='') {
    $teste = new simple_html_dom($url);
    echo 'SIZE: '.$teste->original_size."<br>";
    $teste->find("html");
}
`the error appears again: Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /var/www/html/crawler/simple_html_dom.php on line 1113

Comment: you need to echo or print_r the $teste->find("html")... but try to avoid it because it will print_r a huge object and your server may crash

and if you get the non-object error try using the if(is_object($teste)){//do your code}

Comment: the problem is, after get a 404 error never more the class turn to a valid object again...

Comment: I make some modifications and this code solve my problem... 


thank you

Comment: Now the code:
`$html = @file_get_contents($url);
            if ($html!='') {
                $html1 = new simple_html_dom($html);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<?php
require_once("./simple_html_dom.php");          # simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net

$url="http://www.btolinux.com.br/";
$url404="http://www.btolinux.com.br/error/";

$teste = @file_get_html($url);
if ($teste && $teste->original_size) {
    echo $teste->original_size."<br>\n";
    $html = $teste->find("html");
}

$teste = @file_get_html($url404);
if ($teste && $teste->original_size) {
    echo $teste->original_size."<br>\n";
    $html = $teste->find("html");
}

$teste = @file_get_html($url);
if ($teste && $teste->original_size) {
    echo $teste->original_size."<br>\n";
    $html = $teste->find("html");
}
?>
```

My output was:

```
61206<br>
61206<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using file_get_contents() first?
For example if you use the code:

```
<?php
print_r(file_get_contents("http://www.btolinux.com.br/error/"));
?>
```

You'll see that there's an error, then you can try-catch it.

Comment: I have used, but appears this messages:

Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.btolinux.com.br/error/): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in /var/www/html/crawler/simple_html_dom.php on line 75

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/crawler/TestCrawler.php on line 18


Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/crawler/TestCrawler.php on line 19

Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /var/www/html/crawler/TestCrawler.php on line 20

Answer (score 0):

SUGGESTION:

```
$teste = new simple_html_dom();
$teste->load_file("http://www.btolinux.com.br/");
...
```

... OR ...

```
$teste = file_get_html("http://www.btolinux.com.br/");
```

Comment: Hi, when I use this alternatives, appears this errors messages:

Comment: Hi, when I use this alternatives, appears this errors messages:

Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.btolinux.com.br/error/): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in /var/www/html/crawler/simple_html_dom.php on line 75

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/crawler/TestCrawler.php on line 18


Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/html/crawler/TestCrawler.php on line 19

Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /var/www/html/crawler/TestCrawler.php on line 20